# finding matching characters between two strings

Tags: java, string, char

```
public class findMatching {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String matchOne = "caTch";
      String matchTwo = "cat";
      findMatching(matchOne, matchTwo);
   }

   public static void findMatching(String matchOne, String matchTwo) {
      int lengthOne = matchOne.length();
      int lengthTwo = matchTwo.length();
      char charOne;
      char charTwo;

      while(!matchOne.equals(matchTwo)) {
         for(int i = 0; i < lengthOne && i < lengthTwo; i++) {
            charOne = matchOne.charAt(i);
            charTwo = matchTwo.charAt(i);
            if(charOne == charTwo && lengthOne >= lengthTwo) {
               System.out.print(charOne);
            } else if (charOne == charTwo && lengthTwo >= lengthOne){
               System.out.print(charTwo);
            } else {
               System.out.print(".");
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have created a static method called *findMatching* that takes in two String parameters and then compares them for matching characters. If matching characters are detected, it prints said characters while characters that do not match are represented with an "." instead.

> EX: for `caTch` and `cat`, the expected output should be `ca...` where the non-matching characters are represented with "." in the longer string.

Right now however, my program's output only prints out `ca.` in that it only prints the non-matching characters for the shorter string. I believe the source of the problem may be with the logic of my if statements for *lengthOne* and *lengthTwo*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop will terminate as soon as you meet the length of the shorter string as you are doing `i < lengthOne && i < lengthTwo`. So you need to keep the loop going until you get to the end of the longer string, but stop comparing when the shorter string is out of characters.

Something like this would be able to do the job

```
public static void findMatching(String matchOne, String matchTwo) {
  int lengthOne = matchOne.length();
  int lengthTwo = matchTwo.length();
  char charOne;
  char charTwo;

  for(int i = 0; i < lengthOne || i < lengthTwo; i++) {
    if(i < lengthOne && i < lengthTwo) {
        charOne = matchOne.charAt(i);
        charTwo = matchTwo.charAt(i);
        if (charOne == charTwo) {
           System.out.print(charTwo);
        } else {
           System.out.print(".");
        }
    } else {
       System.out.print(".");
    }

  }
}
```

I am not sure what the point of the while loop is as it would make the program run forever, however maybe you want that as an if?

Comment: Thank you, you fixed my issue. You are right that it wasn't supposed to be a while loop. I intended for it to be an if statement although it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First `for` loop to print all the common and uncommon (".") characters and second `for` loop to print uncommon characters (".") till the difference between the larger and smaller string using absolute (abs) function

Code:

```
          for(int i = 0; i < lengthTwo && i < lengthOne; i++){
            if(matchOne.charAt(i) == matchTwo.charAt(i)){
             System.out.print(matchOne.charAt(i));
            }
            else{
             System.out.print(".");
            }
          }
          for(int j = 0; j < java.lang.Math.abs(lengthOne - lengthTwo);j++){
           System.out.print(".");
          }
```

Comment: This would result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the strings are not the same length.